# Linux save file as soon as it changes

Tags: linux, command

I am trying to execute a script that will write several times in a file.
I would like to save that file every time it changes in Linux.

The idea is that my script runs and as a background task, as sound as my file changes, it is saved in a folder with a different name every time.

I have tried this:

```
while :; do
  watch -n2 -g ls -l /path/to/dir/my_file && cp my_file my_destination_dir
done

code_to_execute
```

but it is not working...
Any hints on how to do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You're not changing the destination filename each time.

Comment: You have an infinite loop, so `code_to_execute` will never be reached.

Comment: Use `inotifywait` instead of `watch` to detect changes to the file.

Comment: You need the full pathname in the `cp` command.